# Security concern regarding PHP image conversion

Tags: php, security, svg, imagemagick

In PHP I'm creating an svg file, injecting some elements posted from a form, converting that svg to a jpg using ImageMagick, and then finally destroying the svg leaving only the jpg version. This all works perfectly. My concern is security and what steps I can/should take to minimize my risk.

Here's the meat of my code...

```
//WRITE THE FILE CONTENTS INTO THE FILE
//If file already exists, it will replace it.
file_put_contents($file, $current);

//START CONVERSION PROCESS
$svg = file_get_contents($file);

$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$image->setCompressionQuality(60); 
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
$image->writeImage($newFileName);
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();

//DESTROY SVG FILE 
unlink($file);
```

My fears are something exploitable being inserted into my svg. If that were the case, would it survive the image conversion? What are some strategies I might employ to make this more safe/as safe as possible.

Answer (score 1):

SVG will inherit all security risks as XML; like [billion laughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs) & [external entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_external_entity_attack) to name a couple. Although most SVG delegate libraries have addressed key issues, your still responsible for protecting against XSS, and sanitizing user input.

> If that were the case, would it survive the image conversion?

Usually not, as the process of re-drawing vector to raster throws out original data. However exploits targeted to stop reading SVG data would persist.

> What are some strategies I might employ to make this more safe/as safe as possible.

- Validate
- Sanitize
- Enforce SSL
- Become familiar with working security practices (like [PCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard)), and adapt.